# Is it acceptable to ask question in comment on all answer rather than in Question's comment?

Tags: discussion

I have recently answered on [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android/32987727#32987727) which has 21 answers.

After few days [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5144855/ruchir-baronia) user has commented on my answer asking other question when i visited question and look at other answers i found that user asks that question in almost all answers asking same thing.

is this acceptable or user can ask on Question's comment rather than Answer's comment?

Comment: For that matter, what is lacking in the accepted, 3000-scoring answer that you seek to address with the addition of your answer? I really don't see why the question even needs 21 answers.

Comment: (Coming back to your question, no, that's not acceptable, that just reeks of desperation and burdens way more people than is necessary.)

Comment: Somebody upvoted one such comment.  That's quite unacceptable.

Comment: I am amazed at the activity on that question. It isn't even like a bunch of people tried to answer it all at once. Not only were most of the answers not even posted in the same YEAR as the question, most were posted after the question was protected. Which means most of the answerers saw that the question had multiple, highly up-voted answers and added their own answer anyway. Apparently answering this question is a good way to get rep. An answer from this year on a 5 year old question has 9 up votes. This is **baffling**.

Comment: But if that user has a question that should either be it's own post or something they can ask in chat. Q&A shouldn't be happening in comments on the main site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not acceptable.  If the user has a question to ask, they should be asking their own question as a question.